# Use CSS to highlight an image?

Tags: css

I have a circle shaped image I want to highlight with red, yellow or green sometimes. Can CSS be used for this?

I know I could do something like `border:#CCCCCC thin solid;` but I want the highlight to be the same shape as the image (circle in this case).

Comment: it definitely can be used. you can use css to create a circle of a certain color to act as a highlight.

Comment: use border-radius to make the border circular.

Comment: So by highlight, do you mean border, or overlay, or…?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this helps:

```
border-radius:50%;
border:#CCCCCC thin solid;
```

50% border radius makes the border (and its content) round shaped.

Answer (score 1):

maybe help:

```
box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px blue;
```

OR

```
border-radius: 20px;
```

Answer (score 0):

If your image is a gif/png with transparent background, setting the opacity will do the trick.

```
.highlight {
    opacity: 0.7;
}

.highlight:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
```